# Error: Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float32 and Float64

Tags: export, google-earth-engine

Here is my link

https://code.earthengine.google.com/ef1f791ab0223983a1177ddb7bd10699

It has 3 bands, all of them are float type.
Why this error to exporting images?
What do I need to modify?

Comment: please put the relevant code here, in the question

Answer (score 5):

Use toFloat() on the image you want to export to get all bands 32-bit Floating values